# Baal Teshuva or Convert?

Tags: baal-teshuva

If you were not raised Jewish and find that you have Jewish Ancestry on your Mother's side via DNA testing... do you still have to go through the normal conversion process or are you considered a Baal Teshuva?

Thanks!